# Получить данные из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте:). Есть вот такой массив, не самый сложный :) :

```
  array(3) {
  ["file"]=>
    string(114) «/var/www/user2/data/www/blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Инженеры-30.7.2014-16.33.526.jpeg»
    ["url"]=>
    string(95) «http://blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/blabla-30.7.2014-16.33.526.jpeg»
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) «image/jpeg»
    }
```

Как из этого массива получить второе (url / string)?
Кавычки-елочки скорее всего просто WP поставил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, решил сам :). Решение - использовать переменную типа `$array['url']` :)